# Can I say Python Tools for Visual Studio is better than Pydev+Eclipse in debugging?

Tags: pydev, ptvs

Assuming you already have Visual Studio, then seems this Python Tools for Visual Studio (PTVS) is a better choice in debugging.

Sometimes, Pydev's debugging will never hit certain breakpoints and just hang(the python native PDB still works), while PTVS works for such scenarios.

Pydev is maintained by 1 man while PYVS is by a team (with commercial interest), so can I say the latter will be better supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can learn more about PTVS debugging in their [documentation](https://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Features%20Debugging).  If you are willing to use the [2.0 Beta release](https://pytools.codeplex.com/releases/view/103101), then you also get mixed mode debugging.  MMD is only one of a handful of features PTVS supports.  PTVS also has full breakpoint support, local inspection, watch windows, immediate window, remote debugging, and a debug interactive window.